# How can I access Google Drive API as a domain administrator or as a Marketplace App?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a marketplace app that I'd like to use to access the Google Drive API.   I'm currently using the gdata API using 2-legged OAuth.  My understanding is that the new Google APIs, including Google Drive API do not support 2-legged OAuth.

How can I access the Google Drive API for my customers' domain without asking each of my customers's users for individual permission?

On my Google Apps Marketplace Vendor page, there is a link to the Google APIs Console, with a project linked to my Marketplace App, but there is no option to create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID. I can only create a Simple API key.

Apparently, you used to be able to use the two-legged OAuth credentials along with the server api key to authenticate, but it looks like that's no longer the case.  I tried to authenticate using this method with an old Google API .net sdk, but got a 401.  I downloaded the newest sdk, and two-legged OAuth is completely missing.  I checked out a copy of the Ruby sdk, because it was used in the video "[Google Drive SDK: Using the Drive API with the Google Apps Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/31225111-2001)", but it looks like (I don't know Ruby) it explicitly forbids two-legged OAuth:

```
case authorization
    when :oauth_1
      STDERR.puts('OAuth 1 is deprecated. Please reauthorize with OAuth 2.')
```

I feel like Google is intentionally ignoring my questions about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use domain-wide delegation to access users' data without asking each user. Details are explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like it will work for domain administrators, but what about Marketplace apps.  When I click the "Register for additional APIs" link for my app, I go to the Google APIs page, but there is no option for creating an OAuth 2.0 client or downloading a key pair.

Comment: Thanks, I did not see this before, but It looks like it's too old.  In the video, you can see that he's using oauth1, and two-legged authentication. All Oauth1, including two-legged has been removed from the .net library.  I tried his approach using an older .net library but still get a 401.  He's using Ruby, which I don't know well, but I checked out the latest version from github, and couldn't find any reference to two-legged oauth in there.